# Reactjs dropdowns, popups, modals, tabs, classToggling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building my final project view in reactjs. I am facing several troubles and want good approaches for these.

To create dropdowns, tabs, accordians, popups modals etc, what should we use, either React states or pure JS long code to toggle classes. Is there any js library for these specific tasks.

When to use objects and when arrays for state.

Comment: http://react-toolbox.com/ Have a look at this lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some popular bootstrap for `React` that I know: [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) and [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

Comment: I don't want to use css, just need js functionality